# jQuery fullcalender.js getting dynamic data from angularjs request using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I have the following output with static data from the following code using fullCalender.js  since I am using ASP.NET Core MVC with AngularJs, so I want to get data from controller through AngularJs ajax request. I want dynamic data from database in which I have a title and start column already and a data also

```
events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2018-02-02',
                    className: 'b-l b-2x b-greensea'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2018-02-07',
                    end: '2018-02-09',
                    className: 'bg-cyan'
                }
```

[image: this is a static data example]

and I am trying to send request something like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calender').change(function(){

            var events = {
                  url: '/Appointment/GetCalenderData',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {

                  }
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What does not work? Did you already try it?

Comment: _fullCalender.js_ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is unclear. It all depends on what data format your server delivers. If it delivers static json formatted fullcalendar event data, then you have nothing to do: just specify the url of the server. If you want something more dynamic, or if the server delivers your own format, use

```
events: function (start,end,timezone,callback) {
   // compute your url here
   // possibly built from start, end and timezone
   $.ajax({url:url,success:function (data) { apply_callback(callback,data) }})
},
...
```

where you must define the function

```
apply_callback = function (callback,data) {
   // transform the data returned by the server into fullcalendar events
   callback(events)
}
```

Details are in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function).